# How to customize the HyperLinkedRelatedField in Django Rest Fraemwork?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Hey I am working with Django Rest Framework. I am using `HyperLinkedRelatedField` from **Rest Framework Serializer**. As shown in image, the `url` is `"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/teams/new/"` but I want it like `"http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/teams/new/join/"`

[image: Same as "url" nut want "url+/join/]

#### Here is the Serializer code

```
class TeamListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    privacy = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=options)
    avatar = serializers.ImageField(default='users/avatar/default/user.png')
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(read_only=True,
                                           view_name='team-detail',
                                           lookup_field='slug')
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = (
            'url',
            'slug',
            'name',
            'description',
            'avatar',
            'privacy',
            'pinned',
        )

        read_only_fields = ('slug',)
```

#### Urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [

           path('<slug:slug>/',
                TeamDetailAPIView.as_view(),
                name='team-detail'),

           path('<slug:slug>/join/',
                TeamMemberCreateAPIView.as_view(),
                name='team-join'),
         ]
```

Comment: show us your urls

Comment: I updated the post buddy, check the urls.

Comment: @iklinac thanks, the hint was enough :). hehe I was just blind forget the url.py file..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

Just by updating the `view_name` to the url I want. I just change the `view_name='team-detail'` to `view_name='team-join'`

```
join_url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(read_only=True,
                                                view_name='team-join',
                                                lookup_field='slug')
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by doing the following:

Serializer.py:

```
class TeamListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    privacy = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=options)
    avatar = serializers.ImageField(default='users/avatar/default/user.png')
    url = serializers.HyperlinkedIdentityField(read_only=True,
                                           view_name='team-detail',
                                           lookup_field='slug')
    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = (
            'url',
            'slug',
            'name',
            'description',
            'avatar',
            'privacy',
            'pinned',
        )

        read_only_fields = ('slug',)

    def get_url(self, obj):
   
       return str(url + "/join/")
```

Comment: yep, this is also the solution. But I have already setup my url in my url files just calling the wrong name. Thanks